# /etc/passwd vs /usr/bin/passwd

Tags: unix, passwd

In my CentOS 7 system (and other Linux flavors), I have noticed that there are two passwd files, /etc/passwd and /usr/bin/passwd. The former contains plaintext information about the users, groups, default shells, etc., whereas the latter is a binary (?) file that the "passwd" command invokes (as suggested by "which passwd").

These may be basic questions, but I have tried my luck with manuals and explanations on forums, albeit not fully clarifying my mental picture:

1) What is the purpose of each file, and why do we have both?
2) Are the two files related -- is the /usr/bin/passwd a binary version of the /etc/passwd that is constantly updated, for efficiency purposes?
3) What are the appropriate permissions on these files (I am getting a "passwd: Authentication token manipulation error" if I try to change the login password of a non-sudoer user from that user's account, which is what prompted this line of questioning to begin with).

Thanks for reading and I am looking forward to your thoughts!

Comment: /usr/bin/passwd is a binary used for setting/changing user's password.
/etc/passwd lists users, their home directories, UIDs, GIDs and shells.
Passwords are stored (encrypted) in /etc/shadow.
If you want to read about /usr/bin/passwd (command `$ passwd`) run `$ man passwd`

Answer (score 7):

The two files are different, and serve different purpose.

- `/etc/passwd` is user database (fun fact: contrary to its name, it doesn't store passwords - those are stored (possibly in hashed form) in `/etc/shadow`) - see `man 5 passwd` (i.e. [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)), `man 5 shadow` (i.e. [shadow(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html)).
- `/usr/bin/passwd` is utility that is supposed to modify user records stored in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. See `man 1 passwd` (i.e. [passwd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html))

Comment: Not fun fact: it doesn't store passwords anymore, but it used to. Hence this is where the name comes from.

Answer (score 4):

1. `/etc/passwd` is the `password file` but it doesn't have to
   contain passwords - see below.  It's a plain text file that contains
   list of users and groups on a given system.  You can read more about
   it in `man 5 passwd`:

   ```
    /etc/passwd contains one line for each user account, with seven fields delimited
    by colons (":"). These fields are:

      ·   login name

      ·   optional encrypted password

      ·   numerical user ID

      ·   numerical group ID

      ·   user name or comment field

      ·   user home directory

      ·   optional user command interpreter
   ```

And `/usr/bin/passwd` is a utility for changing user passwords,
commonly a part of the [shadow
package](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.8/postlfs/shadow.html).
Not that, ironically, users' passwords are not stored in `/etc/passwd`
but in `/etc/shadow` on today's system so `password file` might be a
bit misleading.  From `man 5 passwd`:

> If the password field is a lower-case "x", then the encrypted password
>   is actually stored in the shadow(5) file instead; there must be a
>   corresponding line in the /etc/shadow file, or else the user account
>   is invalid.

A regular user cannot even read `/etc/shadow` because
it does not have a read privilege on this file but can use `passwd`
utility to change his password because `passwd` has `setuid` bit set:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101467/how-does-the-passwd-command-gain-root-user-permissions

2. No, `/usr/bin/passwd` is not a binary version of `/etc/passwd`.
3. See:

   ```
   $ ls -l /etc/passwd
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1335 Jul 14  2016 /etc/passwd
   $ ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
   -rws--x--x 1 root root 77689 Jul  2  2014 /usr/bin/passwd
   $ ls -l /etc/shadow
   -rw-r----- 1 root shadow 719 Aug  5  2016 /etc/shadow
   ```

   You cannot change other users' passwords as the regular user.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Makes sense.

Comment: Although this illuminates my understanding of password management, I was originally brought here by a `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error` when users try to change *their own* password. The permissions for `\etc\passwd`, `\etc\shadow`, and `\usr\bin\passwd` are set up according to your indication, so I suspect that is not an issue. A common problem suggested elsewhere is that the system is mounted read-only, but the only line that is not `rw` in my `mount` output is `tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)`. Could that be the issue?